# Works, but is VERY slow... calling an XML with JS and then adding a JS function to the text from the XML

Tags: javascript, xml, flash

I'm calling text from an XML file with JS and then adding a JS function to that text.  However, the response is very, very slow.  Is there a way I can improve this?

I have two XML files... one that I created, and then another from a database that was created with a flash program.  I want certain features on this flash program to highlight.  I have done this one of three ways:

1. I manually enter the text in and use a JS to highlight the flash features onmouseover (speed is great, but I have to manually enter all of the text in  on the html page and will have to do this for EVERY single flash file (I am doing over 50)  Plus, the data will change frequently, and it would be better to have a single database document rather than going in to each flash file individually.
2. I make a tag in the XML file that contains the JS and when I call it from the page, the entire list populates at once, but it is extremely slow to the point of taking several seconds on each mouseover of each text)
3. I call the XML text with JS and add another JS function for the mouseover.  This works as well, but is very slow (however not as slow as #2, but still very slow) and the JS is very long as I have to call each text individually rather than populating the entire list as I did in #2

Here are the examples for 2 and 3:

**XML for #2**

```
<VIRGINIAREP>
        <DISTRICTS>
            <STATE>Virginia</STATE>
            <DISTRICT>1</DISTRICT>  
            <REPRESENTATIVE>Robert J. Wittman</REPRESENTATIVE>
            <REPWEB>http://wittman.house.gov' onMouseOver='highlight1()' onMouseOut='highlight_clear()'</REPWEB>
            <PARTY>R</PARTY>
        </DISTRICTS>
        <DISTRICTS>
            <STATE>Virginia</STATE>
            <DISTRICT>2</DISTRICT>  
            <REPRESENTATIVE>Scott Rigell</REPRESENTATIVE>
            <REPWEB>http://rigell.house.gov' onMouseOver='highlight2()' onMouseOut='highlight_clear()'</REPWEB>
            <PARTY>R</PARTY>
        </DISTRICTS>
        <DISTRICTS>
            <STATE>Virginia</STATE>
            <DISTRICT>3</DISTRICT>  
            <REPRESENTATIVE>Robert C. Scott</REPRESENTATIVE>
            <REPWEB>http://www.house.gov/scott/' onMouseOver='highlight3()' onMouseOut='highlight_clear()'</REPWEB>
            <PARTY>D</PARTY>
        </DISTRICTS>..... etc.
```

**JS for #2**

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","113CongressC.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='0'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DISTRICTS");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("DISTRICT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " -");
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write("<a TARGET='_blank' href='" +  x[i].getElementsByTagName("REPWEB")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "'>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("REPRESENTATIVE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + "</a>";
   document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write("(" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("PARTY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ")");
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");

</script>
```

**The HIGHLIGHT FEATURE**

```
function highlight() {          
            theMap.features('DISTRICT="1"').highlight(
                {visible: true, fillColor: "#FFFF00", fillAlpha: 1.0}  
            );
        }
```

**XML for #3**

```
<VIRGINIAREP>
            <DISTRICTS>
                <STATE>Virginia</STATE>
                <DISTRICT>1</DISTRICT>  
                <REPRESENTATIVE>Robert Wittman</REPRESENTATIVE>
                <REPWEB>http://wittman.house.gov</REPWEB>
                <PARTY>R</PARTY>    
            </DISTRICTS> ...etc.
```

**JS for #3**

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","113CongressC.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;  

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DISTRICTS");
i=0;


function displayREPS()
{
rep="<a target = '_blank' onMouseOver='highlight()' onMouseOut='highlight_clear()' href = '" + (x[0].getElementsByTagName("REPWEB")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + "'>" +(x[0].getElementsByTagName("REPRESENTATIVE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + "</a>";
district=(x[0].getElementsByTagName("DISTRICT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
party=(x[0].getElementsByTagName("PARTY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

//2 
rep1="<a target = '_blank' onMouseOver='highlight1()' onMouseOut='highlight_clear()' href = '" + (x[1].getElementsByTagName("REPWEB")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + "'>" +(x[1].getElementsByTagName("REPRESENTATIVE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + "</a>";
district1=(x[1].getElementsByTagName("DISTRICT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
party1=(x[1].getElementsByTagName("PARTY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
//3
rep2="<a target = '_blank' onMouseOver='highlight2()' onMouseOut='highlight_clear()' href = '" + (x[2].getElementsByTagName("REPWEB")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + "'>" +(x[2].getElementsByTagName("REPRESENTATIVE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + "</a>";
district2=(x[2].getElementsByTagName("DISTRICT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
party2=(x[2].getElementsByTagName("PARTY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

....etc.

```
//TXT

txt0=district + " -  " + rep + "&nbsp; ("+ party + ")";
txt1=district1 + " -  " + rep1 + "&nbsp; ("+ party1 + ")";
txt2=district2 + " -  " + rep2 + "&nbsp; ("+ party2 + ")";
txt3=district3 + " -  " + rep3 + "&nbsp; ("+ party3 + ")";
txt4=district4 + " -  " + rep4 + "&nbsp; ("+ party4 + ")";
...etc


document.getElementById("showREPS").innerHTML=txt0 + "<br>" + txt1 +  "<br>" + txt2 + "<br>" + txt3 + "<br>" + txt4 + "<br>" + txt5 + "<br>" + txt6 + "<br>" + txt7 + "<br>" + txt8 + "<br>" + txt9 +  "<br>" + txt10 + "<br>";
}
</script>


</head>
<body onload="displayREPS()">

<div id='showREPS'></div>
```

I've also tried: `<REPWEB><![CDATA[<a target='_blank' href='http://wittman.house.gov' onMouseOver='highlight0()' onMouseOut='highlight_clear()'>]]></REPWEB>` for the XML

Any suggestion on how I can do this better and more efficiently with a fast speed?

Comment: Yes, stop using XML files.  If you need to, create a server-side process to strip what data you need from the XML files and dump it in a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using JSON format as opposed to XML. It is much faster to transmit (it is smaller in terms of bytes), also JSON is going to parse much quicker.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It ended up being that the XML file was the problem as it was HUGE and slowing things down.  As soon as I made a small xml, its speed was fine.  But, I will take you up on your suggestion and look into JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem with the XHR object in COM code.
When I use the **responseXML** method instead of the **responseText**, the xml document is very slow to find nodes with XPath queries.
I'm using MSXML6.

- use the **responseText** to get the entire text
- create a DOM document
- load the xml through the **loadXML(string)** method of the new DOM document

and voilà!Really faster! I don't why what kind of DOM document the XMLHTTPRequest creates on **responseXML** to get a so slowly DOM document but it is really faster to create a new one